# SonarQube WS API call on ceTaskUrl not returning anything

Tags: curl, sonarqube

I am using curl to GET from the url. I am trying to fail a build if the quality gate does not pass, but I don't get anything back. I am on mac and in terminal I try "curl ceTaskUrl" (can't put real url) and see no response. Any ideas?

Comment: If it's not returning _anything_ then you're not using `curl` right. What happens when you try your URL in a browser?

Comment: I realized that I needed to pass in the login information for it to be able to return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was not supplying the login information for the website. The command needs to be structured like this curl -u username:password URL.